# Can't run wp7 app via my device

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

i can't run my wp7 app(https://github.com/slodge/face) on my device. I mean, app runs, partially. When i try to call PhotoChooserTask or CameraCaptureTask, nothing happens.

Comment: On emulator everithing is great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you got Zune open? You can't use the photocamera class (or a few others) when Zune is open. Close Zune and it should be fine. I've taken to using WPConnect instead of Zune to allow me do the deployment.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using unlocked (developer) phone / or normal phone. If you try to run the app in locked phone it will not support debugging.

And check if zune is on . if the zune is on means. It will not support the CameraCapture / PhotCapture etc tasks.

Better you try to deploy your xap with the deployment tool. Probably it will work. don't forget to remove you data cable from the device

Enjoy coding